Fano scheme of cubic threefold in characteristic 3
Altman and Kleiman in Foundations of the theory of Fano schemes prove that if $F = F_1(X) \subset \mathbb G(1, 4) = G$ is a Fano scheme of lines on cubic threefold in $\mathbb P^4$ with at most finitely many double points, then the natural map induced by restriction
$$
H^0(G, \mathcal O(2)) \rightarrow H^0(F, \mathcal O(2))
$$
is injective whenever $\mathbb k$ is algebraically closed field of characteristic not $3$, and thus every quadric hypersurface containing $F$ in the Plucker embedding must also contain $G$ at least in characteristic not $3$.
Sadly authors do not mention what happens in the excluded case of characteristic $3$. I'm curious if such quadric can be constructed explicitely in any elegant/compact form (provided it even exists, what also to me is not immediately clear, as the proof is not constructive)

It is not a good idea to simultaneously post the same question here and at StackExchange.

Oh, I didn't know that, sorry. Is there some recommended time that I should wait for an answer on MSE first?

It is not necessary to post the question first on MSE, if it is "research level" then posting here makes more sense. But if you posted it on one site then waiting for a week or two before posting on the other makes sense.

Yes, such quadrics can be constructed explicitly in terms of the polynomial defining $X$. In fact, a five-dimensional space of them can be, one for each linear form in $H^0( \mathbb P^4, \mathcal O(1))$.
Multiplying the polynomial defining $X$ by a linear form, one gets a quartic polynomial. Restricting to any line, one gets a quartic polynomial on the line. Fixing coordinates $(x:y)$ on the line, one gets a quartic homogeneous polynomial in $x,y$. The coefficient of $x^2y^2$ is the desired quadratic form in the Plucker coordinates.
Why is this coefficient a quadratic form in the Plucker coordinates?
A conceptual proof is that the space of quartic homogeneous polynomials in $x,y$ spanned by products of a linear form and the cube of a linear form is manifestly $SL_2$-invariant. This space is (in characteristic $3$) the span of $x^4, x^3y, xy^3, y^4$ since the cube of a linear form is a linear combination of $x^3$ and $y^3$. This (together with $SL_2$ having no nontrivial one-dimensional representation) implies the coefficient of $x^2 y^2$ in any polynomial of degree $4$ is an $SL_2$-invariant function on the space of polynomials. Hence the coefficient of $x^2 y^2$ on the pullback of a polynomial by a $5 \times 2$ matrix is a $SL_2$-invariant function in the matrix entries, hence a polynomial in the Plucker coordiantes. Finally, it must have degree $2$
A conceptual proof, which also gives a means to calculate it, is as follows. Any quartic homogeneous polynomial is a linear combination of products of quadratic polynomials, any any quadratic polynoimal is a linear combination of perfect squares (since the characteristic is not $2$), so any quartic polynomial is a linear combination of products of perfect squares $\ell_1^2 \ell_2^2$ where $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are linear forms. If $v$ and $w$ are a basis for a two-dimensional subspace then the restriction of $\ell_1^2 \ell_2^2 $ to that subspace is
$$ (\ell_1(v) x+ \ell_1(w)y)^2 (\ell_2(v)x+\ell_2(w) y)^2 $$
whose coefficient of $x^2y^2$ is
$$ \ell_1(v)^2 \ell_2(w)^2 + 4 \ell_1(v) \ell_1(w) \ell_2(v) \ell_2(w)  + \ell_1(w) \ell_2(v)^2 $$ $$= \ell_1(v)^2 \ell_2(w)^2 -2 \ell_1(v) \ell_1(w) \ell_2(v) \ell_2(w)  + \ell_1(w) \ell_2(v)^2 $$ $$=  (\ell_1(v) \ell_2(w) - \ell_1(w) \ell_2(v))^2$$
which is the square of a Plucker coordinate.
Similar explicit calculations can give a formula for the coefficient of $x^2y^2$ in the pullback of any monomial, thus a formula directly in terms of the coefficients of $f$.
There exists a geometric description also, but it's a bit strange: I think it's the closure of the set of lines where the configuration of $4$ points in $\mathbb P^1$ obtained by intersecting the line with the cubic hypersurface and a fixed auxiliary hyperplane corresponds to the unique $\mathbb F_3$-point of $\mathcal M_{0,4}$ (which, being unique, is necessarily $S_4$-invariant).
These five quadrics are highly redundant - together they only define a codimension $2$ scheme, which is the locus of lines meeting the cubic hypersurface with multiplicity three at some point. (This condition is equivalent to the cubic polynomial, restricted to the line, being a linear combination of $x^3$ and $y^3$, which is codimension two as it sets two coefficients $x^2,y^2$ to $0$.) The Fano scheme itself will have codimension $4$.

Great answer!!!

Amazing answer, thanks a lot!
